# Pulseaudio: Loopback decreases volume?

Tags: pulseaudio

I'm trying to set up PulseAudio for some streaming, and I thought I had it set up correctly. Apparently I was wrong. I was having some issues with volume in my setup, so I decided to start from scratch.

After running the below commands, any input (program) attached to "stream_spkr" comes out at a low volume, probably about half of what it is supposed to be. The created sink is at 100% volume:

```
pacmd insert-module module-null-sink sink_name=stream_spkr sink_properties=device.description=sink_spkr
pacmd insert-module module-loopback source=stream_spkr.monitor sink=alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
```

I deleted the loopback and used `ffplay -f pluse -i stream_spkr.monitor` to play the input from the null-sink over my speakers, and it's at full volume. This leads me to believe that it is, in fact, the loopback causing the issue.

Any PulseAudio gurus here? I can't for the life of me figure out what the problem is. I checked the module options in PulseAudio's documentation and there doesn't seem to be any options for volume so I must be missing something.

EDIT: Upon further investigation, pacmd shows that the loopback volume is, indeed, 36%:

```
index: 37
driver: <module-loopback.c>
flags: VARIABLE_RATE START_CORKED 
state: RUNNING
sink: 1 <alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo>
volume: 0:  36% 1:  36%
        0: -26.62 dB 1: -26.62 dB
        balance 0.00
muted: no
current latency: 35.78 ms
requested latency: 66.67 ms
sample spec: s16le 2ch 44100Hz
channel map: front-left,front-right
             Stereo
resample method: speex-float-1
module: 35
properties:
    media.role = "abstract"
    module-stream-restore.id = "sink-input-by-media-role:abstract"
    media.name = "Loopback from Monitor of stream_spkr_sink"
    media.icon_name = "audio-input-microphone"
```

Why would it start a loopback at 36% volume, and how can I override that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I know what happened here, I had changed the volume of the sink in Pavucontrol a while back. Pulseaudio kept the setting somewhere and was loading my old volume when I re-added the loopback. Subsequent unload/load of the module-loopback after changing the volume back to 100% proved this.

Comment: Do you think it was restored by `module-device-restore`? ref: [PulseAudio: Saving/restoring settings](https://freedesktop.org/www/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Modules/#index3h2)

Comment: I had a similar issue where i always get distorted volume once i activate module, solved it by removing pulse configuration files in home, [see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/23018/revert-audio-configuration-to-defaults)