# Sound not working after dist-upgrade to 18.04 (from 16.04)

Tags: sound, soundcard

I'm having trouble with my sound after a couple of tries. My sound card is not showing and not having any output. I wasn't able to fix the sound of my ubuntu. I mistakenly do dist-upgrade and don't know how to revert to the working version in Ubuntu 16.04. It was working before I've done dist-upgrade.

I tried all the reinstall and update from all google search I can find. In no avail. This is my last resort to ask for help.

Comment: Install Sysinfo from the Ubuntu Software Center. Sysinfo is a graphical tool that is able to display some hardware and software information. Edit your question adding more info about your hardware. If you feel confident with console [try this suggestions](https://askubuntu.com/a/202533/349837). Does `dmesg` output show any clue?

Comment: @PabloBianchi I tried your suggestion but PulseAudio is misconfigured and don't know what value needs to be in the pulse config file

Comment: If it just your user [this may help](https://askubuntu.com/a/23081/349837). Are you sure you aren't using just another unused output? Play with `pavucontrol`. Take a look to log files on /var/log also dmesg output and tell us your sound hardware info.